# apex:includeScript into script src, what is the related number

Tags: visualforce, javascript

According to this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_includeScript.htm . `<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.example_js}"/>` is actually translated into `<script type='text/javascript' src='/resource/1233160164000/example_js'>`. My question is, what is the number 1233160164000. Is it a fixed number or something I need to retrieve from my org?

I understand there are several benefits by using apex:includeScript. But sometimes I don need to use `<script src=...>`. One reason is I can put it at the bottom of the page so the page loads faster. The other is I can have more control over the execution sequence. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random number is completely unnecessary. It's entirely possible to simply say `/resource/myresource` and get the file. The random number is only there to fool browsers from using an older cached version of the file. You can also use `loadOnReady="true"` with scripts you want to load later; they will be dynamically injected when the page triggers its DOMContentReady event. Generally speaking, included scripts will also be loaded in the order in which they appear in the markup, although you might want to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) if the load order is critical.

Comment: That's awesome. Learnt a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the $Resource with the script tag as well.

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="{!$Resource.example_js}" />
</apex:page>
```

If you open the page and look into your browser console you should see the example_js loaded.

Comment: Thank you for this. I know $Resource is working for relative address within a .zip resource. But I haven't tried with a single js file and thought it wouldn't work. Thanks for pointing that out and I will give it a try.